# What camera does the 6th-generation iPod touch have?

Tags: hardware, ipod-touch

Given that the 6th-generation iPod touch gets its A8 processor from 2014's iPhone 6, it seems likely that other components were improved as well.  Was the camera upgraded to the component used in the iPhone 6 (including the sapphire lens, even?), or is it carry-over from the 5th generation (released in 2012 with components from the iPhone 5)?

I looked at Wikipedia and the iFixit teardowns and I'm having a hard time reconciling the apparently contradictory information.  Anybody able to make some sense of this?

[5th-generation iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod+Touch+5th+Generation+Teardown/10803#s38831)
[6th-generation iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod+Touch+6th+Generation+Teardown/44378#s99494)

[iPod touch (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iPod_models)

Answer (score 1):

It is simply neither the iPhone 6 camera nor the 5th generation iPod Touch camera.

The 6th generation iPod Touch has a camera of its own. Some specs are similar to the iPhone 6 camera, but not all. The camera was upgraded from 5 Mpixel on the 5th Gen to 8 Mpixel on the 6th gen - similar to the iPhone 6. On the other hand, the camera does not have the sapphire crystal lens cover and auto image stabilization features that the iPhone 6 has.

Comment: I see, so it's basically a cheaper version of the camera from the iPhone 6.  That would make sense.  Do you know specifically about the lens and sensor—whether those are the same or different as the ones in the iPhone model?

Comment: They're different... it's not the same aperture (2.2 vs 4.4) and there's a difference in focus pixels, etc.